# How to `spawn eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

Tags: shell, tcl, expect

```
expect << EOF
    set itr 0;
    while true {
        spawn ssh-add "$SSHFILE"
        expect {
            "Enter passphrase for" {
                send "$SPASS\r"
                break
            }
            "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent" {
                spawn eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
            }
            "Error connecting to agent" {
                spawn eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
            }
        }
        incr val
        if { val == 5 } {
            break
        }
    }
    expect eof
EOF
```

`spawn eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` line not working. The ssh-agent process is starting (I can see from `pgrep -xu "$USER" ssh-agent`. I guess it is not exporting properly.

Errors: `couldn't execute "eval": no such file or directory`, `Error connecting to agent: Connection refused`.

```
Error connecting to agent: Connection refused
spawn eval SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-jeU0VXyZBC6x/agent.17424; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=17425; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 17425;
couldn't execute "eval": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn eval "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-jeU0VXyZBC6x/agent.17424; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=17425; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 17425;""
    invoked from within
"expect {
            "Enter passphrase for" {
```

Comment: `spawn eval` is self-defeating. The point of `eval` is to run code in a preexisting shell (and, presumably, a shell that will continue to exist later so the effect of the `eval`ed code can be seen by later processes), whereas `spawn` creates a new process.

Comment: ...and as the error message tells you, there's no such thing as an `eval` executable, so you can't spawn it; it's a thing that can be run _in a shell that's already started_, not a thing that can be run without a shell.

Comment: How to achieve the intended purpose? Is that even possible?

Comment: What _is_ your intended purpose? Do you want to change the shell your program was started from, or are you going to use that agent for SSH connections later while your expect script is still running?

Comment: If the copy of ssh-agent is intended to be used _only later in your `expect` script's execution_, then what you're doing is possible. Otherwise, you'll want to restructure your program to move the `ssh-agent` invocation parts out of `expect` into a shell function (that maybe _starts_ `expect` when it's finished).

Comment: The purpose is to `ssh-add $FILE`. I will run the script by following: `. ./myscript.sh` so that in my current session ssh key can be added.

Comment: Okay, then yes, that's possible; you just need to move some parts out of expect into the shell script that wraps it.

Comment: Right. I can do `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` outside `expect`. But any way to do that inside `expect`?

Comment: You can't make expect _tell the shell that started that copy of expect_ to `eval` something. It can only call eval in a new shell it starts, not in the shell that started it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247752/discussion-between-dr-pb-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: Expect uses the [tag:tcl] language. It's not shell. It cannot directly run shell commands.